# Running `wsgetmail` service via Crontab job CentOS 6

Tags: cron, centos6

I want to run the below via Crontab job and not working but when put them in `sh` file and run the `sh` manually it works fine.

Sh file path: `/opt/etc/rt4/test.sh` and the content as below:

`wsgetmail --config=account01.json`
`wsgetmail --config=account02.json`

Running manually:
`sh /opt/etc/rt4/test.sh` it works fine.

Crontab:
`*/1 * * * *  /opt/etc/rt4/test.sh`

Crontab runs this file but those commands are not working.

I have other Crontab jobs and they are working fine as intended.

Comment: You've not yet [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) us the evidence for "not working", e.g. logs, integer exit status, error messages.

Comment: From the cron tag: **Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.** Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crontab and terminal are two different environments, the wsgetmail perl module command is recognizable for terminal but to make it recognizable for corntab we have to add the full path to the module (wsgetmail) in the shell script.
in this case test.sh should looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/wsgetmail --config=account01.json 
/usr/local/bin/wsgetmail --config=account02.json
```

Answer (score 0):

> Running manually: sh /opt/etc/rt4/test.sh it works fine.
>
> Crontab: */1 * * * *  /opt/etc/rt4/test.sh

Those are not the same thing, as 1st line shebang, and `chmod a+x test.sh`, will affect the behavior.
Either remove "sh" when running manually, or prepend it to the cron command.

---

Run `$ id`, and determine if that's different
from how the cron command runs, perhaps by
having cron log `id` output.
Running as yourself manually,
versus as root (uid=0) under cron,
can change the behavior of that command.

Numerous other things are different
under cron, such as lack of a pty.

---

Take a look at `$ env | sort` manually.
Then run it under `crond`, and note the huge difference.

Pay special attention to PATH.
It is likely to be much shorter under cron,
and that can lead to "command not found"
diagnostics.
But you chose not to share any diagnostic
error messages with us,
so coming up with a definitive diagnosis
of this amounts to a mind reading exercise.